# Keep the values from a stream in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to make some validations in a stream, i'm currently checking for invalid card numbers and was asked if a could persist those invalid card numbers for future validations.

What is the best way to achieve that on Apache Flink.

Thanks

Comment: Where do You want to keep them ? Do You want to validate them in Flink or something else ?

Comment: yeah i would like to keep the stream results in memory or disk so i can use them for further validations

Comment: Okay, so what is the desired use case: 
a) You just want to be able to restart Your job and be sure that it will be able to keep validating properly
b) You want to run another job or component not even necessarily Flink that will use this data to validate

Comment: if you could point me in the right direction of both cases i'll be grateful but i think the case a) is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if You want to be able to restart the job and keep the datam, then I would suggest using a Flink state which is checkpointed. I don't know the exact use case, so I can't tell whether You should use the KeyedState or Operator State. But basically the idea is to keep the card numbers or anything that You are using for validation in state and then cancel Your job with savepoint and whenever You will want to start it again, You can start from the given savepoint. This way You will never have empty list of invalid card numbers. You can read more on the state here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html

As for the case when You want to store the invalid card numbers externally, then You can for example side output the card numbers that were invalid and sink them to Kafka or file. This way You will be able to access them in any application or component. You can find more on side outputs here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html